# Center Positioning two divs (one is dynamic in width) inside container

Tags: css

How would you center position two divs inside a container when one is 'dynamic'? That is, the search input in `content-top-search` changes width from 226 to 462 when you click inside it.

Here's my CSS code:

```
.content-top-buttonsearch-holder {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 816px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.content-top-buttons {
    height: 31px;
    width: 269px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 16px;
}
.content-top-search {
    height: 31px;
    float: left;
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="content-top-buttonsearch-holder">
    <div class="content-top-buttons">
        <a id="all_events_button" href="#" title="Click to show all events happening!"></a>
        <a id="all_venues_button" href="#" title="Click to show all venues in our database!"></a>
        <a id="event_finder_button" href="#" title="Click to search for events!"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="content-top-search">
        <input name="venue-search" class="searchbox" onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'sort parties by venue name':this.value;" value="sort parties by venue name" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you give us your html too ? also we need to know which divs are supposed to be centered. otherwise this here is useless

Comment: I think you will have problems with the floats;

Comment: Here's the example: http://jsbin.com/ukuqas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div style="border: 1px solid green; margin: 10px;">
    <div style="margin: 10px auto; width: 50%; border: 1px solid red; text-align:right">center 1</div>
    <div style="margin: 10px auto; width: 80%; border: 1px solid magenta; text-align:left;">center 2</div>
</div>
```

what's really the 'magic' is the `margin-left|right: auto` in the inner divs. Also they have to have a width.

---

edit
This will not work with floats

---

edit2
Try disabling the float on `.content-top-search` Maybe that is what you want.

---

edit3
http://jsbin.com/ukuqas/5 has another solution
there you have a outer container with `text-align: center` and an inner container with `display: inline-block` This inner container containes the buttons and the search box. All float is prohibited.

Comment: Okay, in that case is there a way to set the width of a specific div in the css of my `.searchbox:focus` property? The reason is that the two divs are beside each other and I can't use percents.

Comment: @pufAmuf ***What*** does not work? Works for me http://jsbin.com/ukuqas/2 or I misunderstood what you want

Comment: I'm sorry, it's my fault. I created an image explanation of how I would like it to look :) http://i.imgur.com/T9FK6.png